# run function in dynamic component when a function is executed in parent angular

Tags: angular, dynamic, factory, emit

I need to execute a function when a function in the parent component of dynamically created component is executed without changing the parent component.

Do you have any idea for me how to tell in child to execute a function when the function is run in the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can override the function of de parent (if the function is
   public) if inject the parent in child(*)

   If you has in parent a function

   ```
     doSomething()
     {
       console.log("I am parent")
     }
   ```

   In your child you write

   ```
     constructor(@Optional() @Host() parent: ParentComponent) {
       parent.doSomething = () => {
         console.log("I am parent") //make the same of the parent

         console.log('I am child'); //and make something more
       };
     }
   ```

   see a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gpj5qi?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts)
2. Another is make the same using a directive
3. Or extend the parentComponent creating a new Component that extends
   from Parent

(*)Really I don't suggest this approach, but if you can not "touch" the parent I can not imagine another way

Comment: thanks!!!! a very well written answer